# SQL deletion without primary key as INT

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

How can i delete when my primary key is a Text in the styles of S1,S2,S3,S4 etc.?

Im trying to use this Query:

```
Query = "DELETE FROM S WHERE SNO =" +rowID;
```

where rowID is S1,S2,S3,S4 etc. Though this does not work but if i change my primary key (SNO) to an ID number for example 1,2,3,4,5.. and then run the same Query it works?

Full delete code:

```
public void Delete() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String query = "";
    //asks the user for a tablename.
 String tablename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which table do you want to delete from?");
 String row = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which row do you want to delete?");

 // checks if the input is equal to any of these names and changes the query thereafter.
        switch (tablename) {
            case "S":
                query = "DELETE S WHERE SNO =" + row;
                break;
            case "J":
                query = "DELETE FROM J WHERE JNO = '" + row + "'";
                break;
            case "P":
               query = "DELETE  P WHERE PNO = '" + row + "'";
                break;
            case "SPJ":
                 query = "DELETE FROM SPJ WHERE SNO = '" + row + "'";
                break;
                 case "s":
                query = "DELETE FROM S WHERE SNO = '" + row + "'";
                break;
            case "j":
               query = "DELETE FROM J WHERE JNO = '" + row + "'";
                break;
            case "p":
                query = "DELETE FROM P WHERE SPNO = '" + row + "'";
                break;
            case "spj":
                 query = "DELETE FROM SPJ WHERE SNO = '" + row + "'";
                break;
        }
Connection c = null;

try {
  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
  c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
  c.setAutoCommit(false);
  System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

PreparedStatement pt=c.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM S WHERE SNO =?");
pt.setString(1,row);
pt.executeUpdate();



  c.close();

} catch ( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e ) {
  System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );

}
System.out.println("You have deleted from " + tablename + " where rowID = " + row);
}
```

Comment: What platform are you using? You should use parameters.

Comment: Netbeans. yeah i look into it.

Comment: No, I mean [tag:android], [tag:java2se], [tag:ajax], ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use preparedstatement like this

```
PreparedStatement pt=connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM S WHERE SNO =?");
pt.setString(1,rowID);
pt.exeuteUpdate();
```

Comment: @Looptech you have made the autocommit false.So its not deleted in the database.Make autocommit true

Comment: @Looptech glad It helped you.Feel free to ask any java related problems

Comment: yeah i actually have another problem if you have time to help me? :)

Comment: @Looptech yes sure,ask me

Comment: It's regarding getting columnnames and then make the program get all the data automatically. it needs to be very dynamic. i could show you what i have done so far. should i open up a new question?

Comment: if you would have time to help me check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543309/dynamic-resultset-java

Comment: @Looptech The question has been removed when I saw now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your input in single quotes

Example:

```
Query = "DELETE FROM S WHERE SNO ='" +rowID+"'";
```

Please aware that above query will introduce [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), instead you may use something like [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: @LoopTech So you now have 3 recommendations to use parameters within 2 minutes. Do it! Nambaris last sentence is a better solution than the SQL he wrote.

Comment: Ive, tried using the single quotes to, i get no erros but it doesn't delete. but i look into preparedstatements.